# Devise integration test always fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, integration-testing

I am trying to test my sign in for Devise in rails, but no matter what I do I get a 401 unauthorized error. I think I have set up my testing wrong or something. I don't think it's a syntax error.

Here is what my fixture looks like.

```
one:
  firstname: John
  lastname: Smith
  email: example@email.com
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(Traveler, 'password') %>
  confirmed_at: 2016-01-02 08:31:23
  confirmation_sent_at: 2016-01-02 08:30:59
```

This is what my controller (integration) test looks like.

```
require 'test_helper'

class TourControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  def setup
    @traveler = travelers(:one)
  end

  test "successful login of confirmed user" do
    get traveler_session_path
    assert_equal 200, status
    post traveler_session_path 'traveler[email]' => @traveler.email, 'traveler[password]' => @traveler.encrypted_password
    follow_redirect!
    assert_equal 200, status
  end
end
```

My test.log looks like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
TourControllerTest: test_successful_login_of_confirmed_user
-----------------------------------------------------------
  [1m[36mTraveler Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "travelers".* FROM "travelers" WHERE "travelers"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 980190962], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-31 23:43:28 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 559ms (Views: 557.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/login?traveler%5Bemail%5D=example%40email.com&traveler%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-31 23:43:29 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"traveler"=>{"email"=>"example@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
[1m[36mTraveler Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "travelers".* FROM "travelers" WHERE "travelers"."email" = ? ORDER BY "travelers"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["email", "example@email.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"traveler"=>{"email"=>"example@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[31mrollback transaction[0m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replace this line

```
post traveler_session_path 'traveler[email]' => @traveler.email, 'traveler[password]' => @traveler.encrypted_password
```

to

```
post traveler_session_path 'traveler[email]' => @traveler.email, 'traveler[password]' => 'password'
```

according to `encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(Traveler, 'password') %>`
I think the test need to login by email: 'example@email.com' / password: 'password'